# how to change overflow and height programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have the below div element. I want to be able to change the `height` and `overflow` attributes programmatically.
I tried to change the height as shown below but it does not change.

Please let me know how to change the `height` and `overflow` programmatically.

**TypeScript/JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementById('select-layer-overlay').style.height = '200px'
```

**HTML/Angular**

```
<div id="select-layer-overlay" style="height: 360px;overflow: auto;" *ngIf="showSelectLayers && selectedSite!=null">
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the same and it is working for me, but since you are using the Angular, it is not preferable to update DOM by directly referring the elements like this, instead you can provide a class name and based on that you can toggle the height and overflow properties.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('select-layer-overlay').style.height = '200px';
})
```

```css
#select-layer-overlay {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="select-layer-overlay" style="height: 300px;overflow: auto;" >Hello</div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: is there any alternative solution. the one you posted is not working either

Comment: It is working here in this snippet as expected right ? When you click on the button below, you can see the div height getting reduced to 200px dynamically.